# Alternative of for loop on a column subsetting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck at a time consumption related problem in pandas:

The code looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"IDs": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   "Month": ["01", "02", "01", "01", "02", "01", "01", "02", "01"],
                   "column1": [0.9, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.5, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8]})

df_list = []
for id in df.IDs.unique():
    temp = df[df.IDs == id]
    temp = temp.groupby("Month").mean()
    temp2 = temp['column1'].ewm(span=3, adjust=True).sum()
    df_list.append(temp2)
```

Note that unique `IDs` contains around 500k elements, the original dataframe df contains around 6 mil records.

Now I used tqdm to check the estimated time and it's taking 14-15 hrs to complete. If I have even loop only for `temp = df[df.IDs == id]` line and the estimated time is same (basically those are pandas function, so it should not make any performance issue). So the problem lies in that line.

Is there any alternative way to do this? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What is `<something>` and what is `func` ?

Comment: Hi @JonClements I have added more details on those.

Comment: Please provide data to make this reproducible on a small scale~ See: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Hi @BeRT2me I have added a sample dataframe

Comment: I take it from your question that your issue is related to the length of time it takes to perform a function.  I am just not sure what it is you are trying to accomplish and "Is there any alternative way to do"  doesn't help me understand.

Comment: Hi @itprorh66 I am not sure what following operation actually called: `df[df.column = x]`...

Comment: also the main time consumption occurring when I am doing 'df[df.column = x]`. So I need an alternative of that in this situation.

Comment: @Stat_prob_001 how close does `df.groupby(['IDs', 'Month']).mean().ewm(span=3, adjust=True).sum()` get you?

Comment: @JonClements That's not giving the same numbers as OPs loop, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: thanks a lot @JonClements, I just have to reindex, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out = (df.groupby(['IDs', 'Month'])
         .mean()['column1']
         .ewm(span=3, adjust=True)
         .sum())
print(out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   IDs Month  column1
0    1    01  0.60000
1    1    02  0.80000
2    2    01  0.85000
3    2    02  0.92500
4    3    01  1.16250
5    3    02  0.78125
```

---

```
out = (df.groupby('IDs')
         .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('Month')
                           .mean()['column1']
                           .ewm(span=3, adjust=True)
                           .sum())
         .stack())
print(out.reset_index(name='column1'))
```

Output:

```
   IDs Month  column1
0    1    01    0.600
1    1    02    0.800
2    2    01    0.450
3    2    02    0.725
4    3    01    0.700
5    3    02    0.550
```

Comment: I do not know why these give different results, but that probably comes from not understanding what `ewm` does.

Comment: "ewm" is exponential weighted moving average. The result I got is fine, it's same when I was using loop.